How to change label automatically after pull request is merged through Github Action
I try to implement an example of changing label automatically after pull request is merged through Github Action.
Find Connected Issue, Assign Label to Issue and Remove 'development' Label from Issue cannot work.
I cannot handle with the issue.
How can I fix it?
Here is the code snippet shown below
name: Assign Label on Merge

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]

jobs:
  assign-label-on-merge:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Assign Label to PR
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.PULL_REQUEST_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.addLabels({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              labels: ['done']
            })

      - name: Remove 'development' Label from PR
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.PULL_REQUEST_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.removeLabel({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              name: 'development'
            })

      - name: Find Connected Issue
        id: find_issue
        run: |
          connected_issue=$(jq --raw-output '.pull_request.body' $GITHUB_EVENT_PATH | grep -o '#[0-9]\+' | head -n 1 | tr -d '#')
          echo "::set-output name=issue_number::${connected_issue}"
        if: github.event.pull_request.merged

      - name: Assign Label to Issue
        if: steps.find_issue.outputs.issue_number
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.PULL_REQUEST_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.addLabels({
              issue_number: ${{ steps.find_issue.outputs.issue_number }},
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              labels: ['done']
            })

      - name: Remove 'development' Label from Issue
        if: steps.find_issue.outputs.issue_number
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.PULL_REQUEST_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.removeLabel({
              issue_number: ${{ steps.find_issue.outputs.issue_number }},
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              name: 'development'
            })



You're 3 major versions behind with github-script (and 2 with checkout), try using the latest version before debugging deprecated code.

@BenjaminW. Can you look through it as I revised it?
